# Is there an app for Flash support for Android 2.1?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, samsung-galaxy-apollo, adobe-flash

Currently I am using Samsung Galaxy 3 (i5801) with Android 2.1. Is there any app available to support flash video ?

Comment: note that even without full flash support, all current Android phones from all popular manufacturers (including Samsung Galaxy 3) can play Youtube (no surprise there). Most Android phones ships with dedicated Youtube app.

Comment: Useful: http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/certified_devices/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an alternative browser, Skyfire, which purports to support at least some Flash videos on Android 2.1.

It should be available in the Market.

[image]

Comment: I'm running 2.2 pn my Droid and I've found that skyfire handles flash video better than the flash plugin

Comment: Does Skyfire support games also or just videos?  I tried some games in Skyfire and they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're in the united states it's just a matter of days before you get your 2.2 update which comes with Flash.  I don't believe any other aftermarket player will decode FLV files for you at this time.

Comment: I am citizen of india. :(

Comment: well... the phone you're using is totally read for 2.2, so, you should be able to find a way to update it manually if you can't wait till your carrier updates it for you.  At that point, flash video will just magically work :)

Answer (score -1):

you can install flash by these steps

The first step is to download flash_for_21.zip to your computer and extract the .apk file.

Now navigate to the market and install “Apps Installer” utility to your phone.
Now connect your Android phone to the computer and copy .apk file to your SD card. Make sure that it is in SD card root and not in a sub folder.
After this launch “Apps Installer” on your phone and follow the on screen instructions to install flash_for_21.apk file.
After installation is complete, simply reboot your phone and there you go! You now have Flash 10.1 on your phone.

[get flash for 2.1](http://www.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/android/apps/flash_for_21.zip)

Comment: why do you write everything in a code tag, mate? It's hard to read

Comment: I tried that.  That didn't work for me.

Comment: That's a fake, Flash doesn't work on 2.1.