# Is there a flash lite installation package for smartphones of android 2.1?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, adobe-flash

I don't know whether installation package for different smartphones of the same OS/version is the same.

But if that's not the case,mine is HTC g3.

Note: I've already tried to install flash player 10.1 but failed,so I'm targeting flash lite now.

Comment: Related question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/343/flash-support-for-android-2-1

Comment: What Android version?

Comment: It's android 2.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flash is only available for Android 2.2+.   You won't be able to install it on any older version of Android.

Comment: Yeah,I'm aware of this,that's why I'm asking about **Flash Lite**.

Comment: Skyfire will play some flash videos.  Other than that, there isn't much else you can do.

Comment: `Flash` and `Flash Lite` are totally different story,`Flash` is not supported until recently,but `Flash Lite` is there for mobile phones the first day it comes out.

Comment: Pretty sure that Flash Lite has never been publically available, it's been available for manufacturers to pre-install (this is how HTC had it on their 2.1 Desire) but I don't think it's been available for download?

Comment: Is this the case with Flash Lite on other smartphones like those of symbian OS?

Comment: @android Who knows, I've been on Android for over 18 months now. Do people still buy other phones? Why?