# Adobe flash for Samsung Galaxy 551 with Android 2.2

Tags: 2.2-froyo, adobe-flash, samsung-galaxy-551

There is any way to view flash animations on web with a Samsung with Android 2.2???

I already tryed to install the Adobe flash apk from market but it is disabled for my phone.

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4315/how-can-i-run-flash-on-a-pandigital-novel-hacked-to-run-android-2-1-eclair/4317#4317

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say what model your phone is? Is it on the Adobe's list of supported devices at: http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/certified_devices/ ?

If you look at the Adobe's published [minimum requirements for mobile Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/systemreqs/#mobile), they list Android 2.2, a Cortex A8 (ARMv7) processor, and a Hardware Vector FPU (floating point maths processor).

I'd have thought the two processor requirements are probably going to be more of a problem than the processor speed requirement, as they mean that Flash is going to be trying to use hardware instructions in the CPU that won't be available in older/lesser specced CPUs, this would definitely stop Flash working. Do you know what processor your phone has?

**EDIT**: According to this [Wikipedia CPU page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSM7000#MSM7227_and_MSM7230) the Galaxy 551 has a Qualcomm MSM7227 chip which is ARMv6 compatible. As Adobe state you need an ARMv7 compatible processor, it looks like you won't be able to run Flash on your phone.

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy 551. (I bought it on Brazil, where i live)

Comment: @stick According to this Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSM7000#MSM7227_and_MSM7230 the Galaxy 551 has a Qualcomm MSM7227 chip which is ARMv6 compatible. As Adobe state you need an ARMv7 compatible processor, it looks like you won't be able to run Flash on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in some older phone which aren't supported by Adobe Flash, it may be possible to install Flash Lite.  It isn't close to full Flash, but can only play simple movie.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU usually cant support it.. there isnt a hack around it except that if you really want to view flash, you can download rockplayer for your CPU type, and play the downloaded flv files.. (flv files work in software decoding mode).